# inline script in footer causes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I build header.html and footer.html and use ajax to append them into html pages.

```
$(function(){     
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",
      url: "header.html",  
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(header) {  
        $("body #header").append(header);  
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("failed call header");
      } 
    }); 
    return false;  
});
$(function(){     
    $.ajax({  
      type: "GET",
      url: "footer.html",  
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(footer) {  
        $("body #footer").append(footer);  
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("failed call footer");
      } 
    }); 
    return false;  
});
```

The header is appended as expected, but footer doesn't work since it has an inline script.

First, after the page loaded, all elements disappeared, only "2023" shown on the page.  footer's style and other styles didn't show, either.

Then, I removed  `// document.write(new Date().getFullYear());` everything in the page shows up, but the year in the footer doesn't show!

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="mainFrame">
  <div class="footerTxt">&copy;
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(new Date().getFullYear()); 
      </script>

,. All rights reserved. 
    </div>
 </div>
```

Then I add @(document).ready, but it doesn't work, either!

```
<div class="grayFooter">
<div class="mainFrame">
  <div class="footerText">&copy;
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() 
        {
        document.write(new Date().getFullYear()); 
        })
      </script>

,. All rights reserved. 
    </div>
 </div>
```

Please take a look and appreciate your help.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a working example like a sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider avoiding using `document.write()`. An alternative could be to insert the year via `insertAdjacentText()` next to the `<script>` element itself:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" id="year">
  document
    .getElementById('year')
    .insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', new Date().getFullYear());
</script>
```

[Working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hmnak2?file=public%2Ffooter.html&terminal=dev)